# Isolation and interpretation of vineyard multispectral data

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation, kriging, multi-band

I have 3 band multispectral raster imagery over a vineyard from which i have created a number of indices e.g. NDVI. The data is fairly high resolution (5cm/pixel) so shows a lot of along vine and across vine variation.  For visualisation (and actual use and actioning of the data) i would like to be able to isolate the actual vines from the background (they obviously stand out really well as they are irrigated and are easily separated with the correct thresholds set) and then interpolate the average between the vine rows to show broad scale variation across the vineyard.  Does anyone have any ideas how i might do this in the QGIS GUI environment?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to play with the symbology of the rasters you have created. You can interact with the histograms of the greyscale single-band indices or the RGB layers themselves in QGIS. See this manual page about changing symbology:

http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/changing_symbology.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have an NDVI and you can see the broad scale variations from one row to the next, then I would extract from the NDVI all pixels that are between some medium to high thresholds = only the pixels that show the vienyard rows themselves with the broad scale variations. All ground pixels will be NULL.

Then I would use an interpolation function such as the GRASS module `r.fillnulls` to interpolate between the rows to "fill in" the null cells.